# Framework for unit test case in titanium appcelerator

Tags: ios, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-titanium

Any frameworks available for writing test cases to Support iOS applications developed using Appcelerator Titanium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recommend ti-mocha (https://github.com/tonylukasavage/ti-mocha) which suited, test cases, supports asserts, skips, advanced validations and many more features.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Will try.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few frameworks for Unit Testing:

- [MockTi](https://github.com/rf/mockti)
- [Titanium-Jasmine](https://github.com/guilhermechapiewski/titanium-jasmine)
- [Ti-Mocha](https://github.com/tonylukasavage/ti-mocha)
- [Ti02](https://github.com/appcelerator/tio2)
- [TiUnit](https://github.com/aca-mobile/ti-unit)
- [TiShadow](https://github.com/dbankier/TiShadow)

But the most of those frameworks listed above are either discontinued or don’t work anymore. And the frameworks that are still working mostly run in the Titanium container/runtime. This means the Titanium project needs to be build and run first which makes the execution process of your tests very slow. Besides that, most of them don’t provide mocking the Titanium namespace (e.g. manipulating/mocking Ti.Network).

We’re using the [TiUnit](https://github.com/aca-mobile/ti-unit) toolset for our Unit Testing in combination with [Istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul) (test/code coverage). TiUnit covers our needs within Unit Testing:

- Fast and execution outside of the Titanium container/runtime
- Mocking all dependencies (e.g. required CommonJS modules)
- Generating a mock for all functions, constants and properties in the
  Ti namespace (Ti)
- Callback, L macro and $ testing

More information can be found on the [TiUnit github page](https://github.com/aca-mobile/ti-unit)

Comment: Great info. Can you also point to some example unit tests using TiUnit? I am really confused and need some examples to learn how it works. Thanks.